# AWS: How to connect to a RDS directly

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc

I'm already able to connect to the RDS in my web server (ecs) and locally as well using the endpoint, just like the documentation. My question is:

Since this endpoint is accessible from my local machine, I think this endpoint makes every request in my webserver run through the internet instead of hitting internally in vpc, like, directly into rds. This idea is supplemented when I resolve the endpoint with `nslookup`, the final IP is a public IP, not an internal (like, 172.x.x.x). The problem with this is just performance (response time) since connecting directly to the same network should be much faster.

if my suspicion is right, there is a way to connect my webserver directly to the RDS without using this public endpoint?

Comment: If RDS endpoint resolves to a public address, you have created the RDS instance without a VPC configuration. You'll have to replace the instance with one in the VPC; you can't move an existing publicly accessible instance into a VPC.  Additionally, you won't be able to directly connect to an RDS instance in a VPC from your workstation; you'll have to tunnel through an EC2 instance to get "into" the VPC across the internet.

Comment: Are you running `nslookup` from an ECS task or from your local machine? To verify that ECS is using an internal IP, you can connect to the database and list current sessions (the way to do that will be dependent on your DBMS, which you don't specify).

Comment: @erik258 - you seem to be describing an "EC2 Classic" RDS deployment, but that hasn't been supported for years (and AWS forced everyone using that type of deployment to move their instances into a VPC). If you're running in a public subnet of a VPC, with a public IP address, you can definitely connect from outside the VPC, no tunnels needed.

Comment: EC2 Classic has nothing to do with it.  RDS instances are either in a VPC or not in a VPC, the latter of which meaning publicly accessible in the sense that it has a public IP.  There is no option for both public IP and VPC Private IP.  Thus, if the OP is correct in saying the endpoint resolves to a public IP, then that will be the case both inside and outside a VPC.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the comments. I checked the `nslookup` targeting the same endpoint, but instead of doing it in my local machine, I ran inside my webserver, and to my surprise, the IP was internal, `172.x.x.x`. So, AWS is capable of identifying the origin of the request and creating a better route for it (probably by resolving the DNS to check that)

Comment: VPCs provide a resolver that will resolve "public" EC2 and RDS hostnames to their private IP address when queried from inside VPC: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-dns.html#AmazonDNS